# Reliability Definition For Twitter

Tags: twitter

What is the exact Definition for **Reliability of twitter**,and what are the key attributes consider when making Twitter Reliable according to programming languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Reliability of a system/application(can be twitter), there are few aspects,

- ability to remain operational over time
- probability that the system will not fail to perform its intended functions
- how users and other systems can be dependable of the given application

Reliability also affected by other attributes like,

- availability
- accuracy
- predictability